# Ramp up time in Jenkins not reducing tps

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have a Jmeter script which I am running from local environment and achieved 20 tps(transactions) per second.

I have moved the same script to Jenkins and ran it from there. It worked as expected.

My Next step is to reduce tps from 20 to 2.

So I introduced Ramp up time of 30 seconds and it worked as expected from local environment.

I moved the script to jenkins, it gave me **20 tps** when I run the script from jenkins.

Can someone tell me why this is happening and what I need to do to fix this.

I have tried several approaches like hard coding the ramp up time, creating a new jenkins project with new script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is wrong without seeing your full [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration, normally people use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) for throttling JMeter's throughput to the given number of requests/transactions per second

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can consider using:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) (however it's precise enough on "minute" level, for the first minute of your test execution you will need to manipulate the load using the ramp-up approach
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)  which is more powerful and "precise" however it's configuration is more complex and you need to provide test duration, units, etc.
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) which is kind of a balance between precision and simplicity however it's a custom [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) so you will have to install it on Jenkins master/slaves